# 特定の出力がされるまで処理を繰り返し、出力されたら処理を停止する方法

Tags: bash

特定の出力がされるまで処理を繰り返し、出力されたら処理を停止する方法がわからないので、ご教示ください。

例えば、特定の文字列が出力されるまで、pingを繰り返そうとする場合、
1.ping.txtに文字列"time out"が出力されるまでpingを実行
2.time out が含まれていれば、再度pingを継続
3.time out が含まれていないか、試行回数が10回に至れば、"終了"をecho
と動作させることを仮定しています。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
ipaddr="10.0.10.101"
count=10
ping -c $count $ipaddr > ping.txt
if echo ping.txt | grep 'time out'
then
/繰り返し/
else
echo "終了"
fi
```

Comment: 非建設的なコメントを削除しました。指摘をする時は改善点も添えていただけるとよいと思います。[メタにこちらのような内容の質問をどう考えるかについて議題をあげました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1688/30)ので、ご意見のある方はそちらに回答をいただけるとうれしいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pingの結果をgrepで判定するのは次の理由で得策ではありません。

- pingのエラーはタイムアウト以外にもある。(TTL expire、host/network unreachable)
- タイムアウトの場合に"time out"と表示するとは限らない。OS Xのpingも黙ってるはず。実装によっては日本語で表示する場合もある。

pingはエラーがあった場合0以外の終了コードを返すので、それによって分岐できます。

```
#!/bin/sh 
ipaddr="10.0.10.101"
count=10
loop=10
for i in `seq $loop` do
    ping -c $count $ipaddr > ping.txt && break
    sleep 5
done

echo '終了'
```

`ping.txt`の用途が単に結果判定用で保存しておく必要が無いなら`ping.txt`の代わりに`/dev/null`にリダイレクトします。

Comment: まぁ、「ping の出力結果に特定の文字列が含まれる場合」ということで grep を使った次第です（タイムアウト以外は一回で打ち切りのかな？と）。もっとも、質問者さんは ping がどの様な場合にどんなエラーメッセージを返すのかについてはほとんど知らないみたいですが。。。

Comment: たしかに他のエラーメッセージも抜けもれなく考慮しないといけませんね・・・。装置が起動したか簡易的に調べたかったので、ひとまずタイムアウト以外は1回で打ち切りで割りきって考えていました。

Answer (score 3):

以下は `grep` の `-m` オプションを使うバージョンです。

> grep(1)
>
> ```
> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>   Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
> ```

※ OSX にデフォルトでインストールされている grep コマンドには `-m` オプションがないかもしれません。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
ipaddr="10.0.10.101"
count=10
msg="timeout"

for ((i=1;i<10;i++))
do
  if ping -c $count $ipaddr | grep -q -m 1 "$msg"; then
    sleep 5
  else
    break
  fi
done

echo "終了"
```

なお、"timeout" を検索していますが、"timed out" で検索すべきではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

リダイレクトにはバッファがあります。 `ping.txt` には ping 操作でバッファが一定程度貯まった後書き込まれ始めるので、その方法では処理を停止出来ないです。

`-c count` の代わりに、 `while loop` と `＄？` を使うと解決出来ると思います。

```bash
#!/bin/bash -v
ipaddr="www.google.com"
count=10
rm ping.txt

while [ $count -gt 0 ]; do
        count=$(( $count - 1 ))
        ping -c 1 $ipaddr >> ping.txt
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then   # fail -> reset;
                                # you can also only check error code for timeout according to man page,
                                #        2       The transmission was successful but no responses were received.
                count=10
                sleep 5
        fi
done

echo "Success"
```

Comment: バッファの話。 私は unbuffer ( [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) package )も使えるかもしれないと思いました。

Comment: pingが終了した時点でバッファはフラッシュされるので、質問の文面通りの`for i in `seq 10`; do ping -c 10 $ipaddr > ping.txt ; grep "time out" ping.txt ; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then break; fi;  done` でも処理が終了しないことはありません。また、そのスクリプトはpingが失敗し続けると無限ループするのでは。

Comment: 5秒後に再度pingを実施はtime outの時はずです、つまり１０回連続successしないと終わらない　と私が理解しています。