# iperfで上り/下りのスループット測定を別々に、複数回連続で実行したい

Tags: iperf

例えば、下り10回、上り10回のスループットの自動測定をしようとする場合に、
単にループをまわすだけでは、上りの測定と下りの測定が同時に10回実施されてしまいます。

上り/下りのスループット測定を、それぞれ10回ずつ別々に計測するよう、スクリプトを書き換えたいと思っています。

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_DIR="/Users/"
a=0
while [ $count -gt 0 ]; do
count=$(( $count - 1 ))
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -i 1 -t 30 -f m -d >> ${TEST_DIR}TCPDL1.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
count=10
fi
done
```

構成

```
Android(10.0.0.2)-----router(10.0.0.1)-------PC(10.0.0.3)
```

Comment: シェルスクリプトで10回ループする方法については、あなたの過去の質問 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6407/ で回答がついています。その内容を反映していないのは何か意図があるのですか？

Comment: 意図はございません。新しいコードに差し替えます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 元質問の回答のコメントにも書いたのですが、そのスクリプトは条件によって無限ループします。それは意図通りですか？

Comment: @ぽぽたん どう質問を変更すればプログラム作成依頼から脱却できるかを付け加えるか、よろしければ[こちらのメタ質問](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1688/30)にご意見ください。（上記コメントについては建設的ではありませんので削除します）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iperfを使うなら、`while loop`は必要じゃないと思います。

上り/下りの回数は「`-t $IPERF_TIME`（合計時間）／`-i $IPERF_INTERVAL`（間隔時間）」に成ります。
`Interval`は１秒の場合に、`Time`を１０秒を設定すると１０回に成ります。

それにここは、`-d, --dualtest`より、`-r, --tradeoff`を使うべきと思います。
`-r, --tradeoff`を使うと、上りの後下りを実行します。

だから、下り10回、上り10回はこのように見えます：

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -i 1 -t 10 -f m -r >> ${TEST_DIR}TCPDL1.txt
```

詳細には`man page`、まだはこのサイトをご参考して下さい：
https://iperf.fr/#tradeoff